# WordPress 500 server error when using wp-config.php permissions at 0440

Tags: php, wordpress

Any reason why the site would crash when changing permissions of the wp-config.php to 0400 or 0440 to prevent unauthorized access to view the credentials.

This is recommended from WordPress themselves, and many security blogs. But in reality, when you change the permissions, the site crashes with a 500 error.

https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/#shared-hosting-with-suexec

Answer (score 0):

The webserver needs to be able to read the credentials. You can use `setfacl -m u:www-data:r wp-config.php` (replace www-data) with the user your webserver runs as

To figure out the user your web server runs as, you can use

```
<?php
echo `whoami`;
```

And access it with a browser or curl.

Comment: What exactly does that do? I see that it set permissions to 0440, but doesn't appear to be the same as chmod 0440 results?

Comment: It allows Apache to read the file. Use *getfacl* to see the update